# PySerial - carriage return (\r) not working as expected

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to communicate with a board via serial (rs232) port using PySerial.

The board is a Renesas rl78 and below is my sample code. (Basically what I'm trying here is to execute some pre-defined commands. So here `commands` is again a command that returns a list of other commands)

```
import serial, time, io

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/cu.usbserial"
ser.baudrate = 19200 # as used for HyperTerminal
ser.timeout = 10 #non-block of 10 seconds
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonoff = False
ser.rtscts = True
ser.dsrdtr = True
ser.dtr = True
ser.rts = True

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.is_open:

    try:
        #ser.reset_input_buffer() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        #ser.reset_output_buffer() #flush output buffer, aborting current output

        #write data
        ser.write(b'commands\r')
        ser.reset_input_buffer()

        time.sleep(2)

        in_wait = ser.in_waiting

        while True:
            if in_wait != 0:
                output = ser.read(in_wait)
                print(output)
                break
            else:
                break

        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

And from the device's standpoint, we have to hit `return` (carriage return \r) in order to execute a command using any terminal application. i.e HyperTerminal or [Serial](https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/serial/) for Mac.

So the above code does not return any output but just an empty string (this is what you get in the terminal when you just hit return (\r)). The device is behaving like it got a return (\r) and the command is completely ignored.

To make sure that it is not an issue with PySerial I tried to use PySerial's [miniterm](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.miniterm) to get this terminal behavior, and I was able to successfully execute the commands

Again the catch here is to set CR as the EOL to get the commands to execute successfully.

```
python -m serial.tools.miniterm -e --eol=CR
```

So I'm puzzled here on what is wrong with my code and why it is not executing the commands.

Comment: This might be a buffering issue... You could try to write your commands, then flush the buffer, then write the carriage return and then flush the buffer once again.

Comment: I agree with @Rightleg, that this is probably related to input/output. I'm not entirely sure that your code to read the input is correct. I cannot debug this for you, so here's some ideas. Do you really need to reset the input buffer and is there a chance that this throws away pending input? Does the loop work correctly? What happens when you just do a ser.read() without checking for in_wait?

Comment: @Rightleg Tried your solution, but still no luck.!

Comment: @rje If I do not reset the buffer it returns just empty (None) and it doesn't matter if I use read() or in_wait, the catch here is \r if I do not use \r nothing will return. If I use \r it is returning the default output specified in the Renasas code, which is an empty string ('') I confirm this since I can debug the Renasas code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just revise the command:

```
ser.write(b'commands\r')
```

to this:

```
ser.write(b'commands\r\n')
```